# How to fix permission denied in php?

Tags: php, web

I am trying to write code that writes a file to a directory on a surfer. I am using the function fopen("textfile.txt","w") but I get the message:

> Warning: fopen(testfile.txt)[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in G:\PleskVhosts....\contribute.php on line 57

How can I fix this?

Comment: What permissions do you have for the folder that you are trying to write `textfile.txt` into? You must have at least 755 for writing permissions I believe

Comment: @BenPearlKahan there's normally very little reason to give *nobody* any permissions - 750 would do.

Comment: Quick googling would have helped me there... 75* was the important part! Cheers.

Comment: As an aside : http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Answer (score 0):

You need change permissions for that file. If you use linux try chmod 755, if use windows change permission manually.

Comment: **never** 777 anything - especially if it's under the doc root, you're just asking for trouble!

Comment: The problem is the file is on a webserver, can I still use one of the methods you described?

Comment: if it on server you can use chmod 755,  777 give all permissions, its only for local, dont use it on server it can damage you security.

Comment: Yes you can on webserver, which server you use?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I have actually done it now, I am using Plesk Hosting (I think) I just needed tick a few boxes.

Comment: @Joseph in an ideal world no file that can be written to by the web server should ever be readable over HTTP (though this isn't always entirely practical, say with a CMS that creates product images); so if that text file is only ever going to be read by PHP either put it in a directory **outside** the document root or containing an .htaccess file with **Deny from all**. If the directory is *owned* by Apache you can use something like 700 but if you need FTP access as well (and that's in the same group as Apache) you'll need something like 750.

Comment: Vahe would you update your answer with the details in the comment and a more suitable chmod value ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web server user have the right permission to the folder you are going to create files.

So change the mode of the folder with 75*,add the web server user to the group of the folder.You can check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your project deployed on linux you can use something like this for changing folders/files permissions

```
sudo find /path/of/project -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; ; sudo find /path/of/project -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```